# Disable y-scrolling?

Tags: jquery, html, css, video, scroll

I have an issue.. I have overflow set to hidden, but am still able to scroll with my mousewheel, how can I disable this? I have a video as background.

html code:

```
<video src="background/background1.mp4" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" id="background"> </video>
```

css:

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    min-width:720px;
    font-size: 13.5px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    font-size: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;    

}

#background{
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 320px;
    min-height: 180px;
}
```

overflow:hidden; works for the x-scrolling, and the X and Y scroll-bars are both gone, yet I'am still able to scroll down with my mouse wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this in your css file:

```
html{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Edit your body to also contain:

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```